# C++ CLI (Managed) и C++ - это одинаковые или разные языки?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

`C++ CLI` и `C++` - это одинаковые или разные языки?

Суть в том, что получаю ошибки при инклуде стандартных для `C++` виндовых либ, таких как `<windows.h>` и т.д., так же не могу подключить часть типов, например `TCHAR` из `<tchar.h>`.

Может конечно где то и мои ошибки, но в целом как я понимаю совместимость этих языков печальная?

Comment: >виндовых либ, таких как #include \n Это не "либа". Это директива включения содержимого файла в другой файл. "либа" будет после неё в кавычках или угловых скобках.

Comment: а что `windows.h` уже в `с++11` стандарте есть? А под линукс как?)

Comment: @pavel, поправил вопрос. В целом имелась ввиду   совместимость, универсальность обычного c++ и c++ cli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это совершенно разные языки.

C++/CLI, кроме «обыкновенного» C++, содержит ещё и управляемые (.NET-)типы, и связанные с этим ключевые слова `gcnew`, `ref class` и тому подобное.

---

C++/CLI — это обвязочный язык, нужный для продвинутых сценариев использования нативного и управляемого кода. На нём не стоит писать большие проекты. Если вам нужны вычисления на C++, и UI на .NET, по моему опыту проще всего представить это в виде *трёх* модулей: чисто нативные вычисления, UI на C#, и обвязочный код на C++/CLI. Ну или нативные вычисления можно упаковать в кусок с C++/CLI, если не хотите аж три модуля.

---

С точки зрения совместимости, нативный код на C++, который компилируется MS Visual Studio, должен с минимальными изменениями компилироваться и под C++/CLI. Проверьте, что у вас нигде нет управляемых header'ов в вашем нативном коде.

Comment: а чем плохо на нём писать проекты? Я писал когда-то курсовую на нём, удобно библиотеки подключать С/С++ а писать через `gcnew` и так далее. Можно чуть подробнее этот момент?

Comment: Так и есть, был управляемый хидер в нативном файле, он и дает ошибку.

Comment: @pavel: Получается совершенно ужасный синтаксис, ну и некоторые фичи (например, `out`-параметры) просто не поддерживаются. Особенно трагично отсутствие async/await.

Comment: @Align: Ага, уберите его, ему там не место.

Comment: @pavel, насчет Async Await полностью согласен с VladD, просто посмотрите как пришлось извращаться девелоперам Chilkat, которые под .NET пишут именно на CLI, тихий ужас...: https://www.example-code.com/csharp/smtp_async.asp

Comment: Я cli как замену C/C++ а не C# использовал.

Comment: @pavel, я же наоборот, пытаюсь использовать как комфортный враппер кода на C++ для C#. Просто замучался писать классы враперов на p\invoke с вечными проблемами совместимости типов, выделением памяти через маршаллинг и т.д....

Comment: Угу, P/Invoke хорошо работает на простых вещах, а более сложное маршаллирование приходится делать на C++/CLI.